# Reconstruct ARIMA model with parameters

Tags: python-3.x, arima, pyramid-arima

I have the below parameters of ARIMA model using to_dict function of auto_arima in pmdarima package. Can I reconstruct the model which can be used to predict results using this dictionary object?

My dictionary looks like:

```
 {'pvalues': array([1.4, 1.7, 9.4, 9.3]),
     'resid': array([1.1, 1.0, 1.9, 2.8, ....]),
     'order': (0, 0, 1),
     'seasonal_order': (0, 1, 1, 7),
     'oob': nan,
     'aic': 520.0923760929898,
     'aicc': 521.2034872041008,
     'bic': 527.9735437471983,
     'bse': array([2.5, 9.0, 1.3, 9.1]),
     'params': array([ 9.6,  5.4, -9.9,  6.9])}
```